# IOS Location Update with NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, locationmanager

I want to get location updates exactly once per second.  This interval is important for an animation I want to create to keep true-to-life speed over the ground.  I understand that [myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] will automatically poll "didUpdateToLocations", but it is not quite exactly once per second.

Is there any way to use NSTimer to get my location exactly once per second?

Thank you
-jj

Comment: It's every second, just DO NOT set any filtering, or activity type. Also set the accuracy to best and you will receive location updates every second

Comment: I'm telling you, its not every second, there are lapses.  I just set a simple counter to increment each time my "didUpdateToLocations" is called, along with a time formatted string, and its evident that it is not quite exactly every second.  Actually, the first few calls are extremely quick, ie: approximately 5 calls to "didUpdateToLocations" within the first second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)startUpdatingLocation
    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateLocation {
    CLLocation location = self.locationManager.location;
    // do all the work here
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // do nothing here
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex-alex!  This worked, however I had to specify the "didUpdateLocations" function, even though I don't do any work within that function.  Without it, the location/altitude/heading/etc. would not update.

Comment: @MrJoeHimself If your edit for this answer is rejected, ask Alex-alex to update this answer so that you can accept it. Otherwise you can post your own answer and accept it.